# React bootstrap-keep current tab active even after refreshing

Tags: react-bootstrap

hello i have seen a lot of example to prevent tab refreshing to the initial state,but i have no idea if it is from react bootstrap..can someone tell me how to prevent the tab active even after refreshing for bootstrap

here is the code

```
<Tab.Container id="left-tabs-example" defaultActiveKey="first">
  <Row>
    <Col sm={3}>
      <Nav variant="pills" className="flex-column">
        <Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Link eventKey="first">Tab 1</Nav.Link>
        </Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Link eventKey="second">Tab 2</Nav.Link>
        </Nav.Item>
      </Nav>
    </Col>
    <Col sm={9}>
      <Tab.Content>
        <Tab.Pane eventKey="first">
          <Sonnet />
        </Tab.Pane>
        <Tab.Pane eventKey="second">
          <Sonnet />
        </Tab.Pane>
      </Tab.Content>
    </Col>
  </Row>
</Tab.Container>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "refreshing"? Rerender or page reload?

If latter you have to persist the value somehow and get it on page load. You can do it with localStorage for example.

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage